# Polymer component iron-ajax make two requests

Tags: polymer

I have a custom element using iron-ajax. I don't know why the request occurs twice. This is my code:

```
<template>

    <div style="text-align: center" hidden="{{!cargando}}">cargando ... <br />
        <paper-spinner alt="cargando ..." active="[[cargando]]"></paper-spinner>
    </div>

    <ficha-folleto datos="[[ajaxResponse]]"></ficha-folleto>

    <iron-ajax 
        auto 
        url="backend/api.php?operacion=folleto&idf=[[idf]]&len=[[len]]" 
        handle-as="json" 
        verbose=true 
        last-response={{ajaxResponse}} 
        loading="{{cargando}}"> </iron-ajax>
</template>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "folleto-digital",
        properties: {
        }
    });
</script>
```

The call is from this page:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="elements/folleto-digital/folleto-digital.html">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
    <folleto-digital idf="" id="folleto"></folleto-digital>
    <script src="js/funciones.js"></script>
    <script>
        var idf = getParameterByName("idf");
        var folleto = document.querySelector("#folleto");
        folleto.idf = idf;

        var len = getParameterByName("len");
        folleto.len = len;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And I'm requesting this url: folleto.html?idf=1&len=es

All is working fine, but there are two request:

1. api.php?operacion=folleto&idf=&len=
2. api.php?operacion=folleto&idf=1&len=es

The Polymer documentation says about auto param:

"If true, automatically performs an Ajax request when either url or params changes"

So I think the param at the begining have value="" and then take the values from the querystring and because of that request twice.

How can I fix this to do one and only one request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When [`<iron-ajax>.auto`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax#property-auto) is true, the element automatically generates the request if the `url` is a non-empty string. Since the `url` has a non-empty value even when `idf` and `len` are blank/empty, the `<iron-ajax>` generates a request even before you've set `idf` and `len`.

If you want `<iron-ajax>` to send the request only when `idf` and `len` are set, you'd need to remove `auto`, and add a complex observer on `idf` and `len` that generates the request only when both values are not empty.

```
// template
<iron-ajax id="ajax" ...>
```

```js
Polymer({
  is: "folleto-digital",

  properties: {
    idf: String,
    len: String
  },

  observers: ['_sendRequest(idf, len)'],

  _sendRequest: function(idf, len) {
    if (idf && len) {
      this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks!

Comment: @Jaime No problem :)